# How to read a string with SOS?

Tags: .net, memory-management, windbg, crash-dumps, sos

I am analyzing a crash dump with WinDbg and SOS ([How to debug System.ExecutionEngineException in a framework code of a managed application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488938/how-to-debug-system-executionengineexception-in-a-framework-code-of-a-managed-ap)).

I am able to list objects of certain type on managed heap:
String

```
!DumpHeap -mt 7239afb0 -min 50

I can look at the class:
!DumpObj 0x0a7be6a4
Name:        System.String
...
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
String:      C:\Program Files (x86)\XSLStylesheets
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
7239c770  40000aa        4         System.Int32  1 instance       74 m_stringLength
7239b9a8  40000ab        8          System.Char  1 instance       43 m_firstChar
7239afb0  40000ac        c        System.String  0   shared   static Empty
```

And now **How to read a string value?** and **How to access a string when it is a field of a class?**

```
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
...
7239afb0  4000719        c        System.String  0 instance 01182390 m_Name
```

**Edit**

Because I get the answer after asking in a comment, I put an explanation here. To get string value just use `!do address` or `!do -nofields address` (!do =!DumpObj). In the result is the line starting "*String:*" and this line contains the desired value (in my case it contained a path and I did not believed to be a right value).

To access an object which is a field of another object we use the value from the column `Value` as an address for !do. So for the field m_Name from example we run `!do 0x01182390`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!do` gives you the string value as part of the object dump.  If you want to see the string fields of an object, then you need to run `!do` on the field value.  `!sosex.mdt` is a bit more efficient in this regard, as it will list the string values next to string fields.

Comment: Thanks for sosex http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx. With !mdt address I can see values of String fields. But I still would like to know how to do it with SOS. With !do I get only listing which is in the question and I don't know how to access a field value (what is the address) and how to read string.

Comment: As I said, you do that by running !do on the string fields of the previous object you dumped with !do.  In your example above: !do 1182390.

Comment: The address is in the "Value" field.

Comment: OK. The information about value was the key one. No I understand it. I also did not recognize that the "String: ..." !do result is the string value. A randomly chose string did not contain anything recognizable.